# Converting sql script to mdf

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a project that has to be turned in tomorrow. For this project I use a SQL Server Express database running on a remote server.

Now, I need to generate a `.mdf` file from the remote database. I have searched everywhere, and I can not find a proper solution.

I have scripted the database to a `.sql` file, but I can't find a way of executing it against a local `.mdf` file. Either I can create a `.sdf` which will not work, or connect to a database engine.

Help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.mdf` is the SQL Server's datafile format.

So you need to these steps:

1. connect to your local server
2. create a new database
3. run the `.sql` script against it
4. detach that database

Now, after all the steps, you can copy the resulting `.mdf` file from the SQL Server data directory to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't generate an MDF file from the remote database.
You can create a local database with a script like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE [test_db] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'test_db', FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\test_db.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'test_db_log', FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\test_db_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET RECOVERY FULL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO
USE [test_db]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.filegroups WHERE is_default=1 AND name = N'PRIMARY') ALTER DATABASE [test_db] MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] DEFAULT
GO
```

And then run you sql script to create  tables and populate them with your data.
After this you have two options.

- Repeat the procedure on your customer machines
- Detach the database and get the MDF and LDF file to your customer,
  then try to reattach it

(Of course this assumes the two SqlServer use the same version)